# How to set color of UIButton type: .system for tvOS in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, tvos

I am creating an app for tvOS. I am trying to set the color of an UIButton but does not know how to get I t right.

```
var buttonA: UIButton(type: .system)
var buttonB: UIButton(type: .system)
...
buttonA.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
buttonB.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

I am happy with the result when the button is in focus but when the button is not in focus I get an ugly result. The green button has a colored layer that is missing its cornerRadius.

[image]

How do I color the buttons correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buttonA.layer.cornerRadius = 10

Answer (score 0):

These values are not customizable in instances of UIButton for tvOS out of the box. You have to create your custom solution in order to have your custom layout.

You can take a look to the implementation of this component for further details https://github.com/dcordero/FocusTvButton